# How to subtract background from a video in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, video-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to detect potatoes on roller belt. I have created mean background from empty belt images and want to subtract it from each frame of the video and play back but not sure how to achieve this.

In other words, I would like to do something like this, but with each frame of the video:

```
>> Z = imread('mean.jpg');
>> X = imread('beltpotatoes_1.jpg'); 
>> C = Z - X;
>> imshow(C);
```

My sample data:

Mean background (mean.jpg): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_M7fjkKw1r3d0o3VHg1dXVFNmc/edit?usp=sharing

avi file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_M7fjkKw1r3a3lhdl91bGFLSjQ/edit?usp=sharing

belt with potatoes image (beltpotatoes_1.jpg): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_M7fjkKw1r3SURDV19ud1VBQjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Z = imread('mean.jpg');
VR=VideoReader('Video.avi');
NumInFrames=get(VR,'NumberOfFrames');

VW = VideoWriter('new.avi');
open(VW);

for (frame=1:NumInFrames)
    CDatas(:,:,:)=read(VR,frame) - Z;     
    writeVideo(VW,CDatas);   
end
close(VW)
```

Comment: I get an array dimentions error while using - operator "Array dimensions must match for binary array"

Comment: is your Z rgb or gray?

Comment: that's strange to me. are your size(read(VR,frame)) equal to size(Z)?

Comment: Not sure... <1080x360x3 uint8> that is the size of Z

Comment: the error occurs because the frame size in your avi is different from Z. try typing  [m,n,p]=size(read(VR,frame));, and resize your Z to [m,n,3] as well (p=3)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47531/discussion-between-jaspernorth-and-lennon310)